# If A is a $3\times3$ matrix such that $\det(A) = 4.$ What is $\det (A + A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Title's all there is to say.
I'm very new to linear algebra and haven't wrapped my head around determinant rules yet.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you multiply one row / column of a matrix by a constant scalar, what's its determinant?

Comment: Try with an example, say $A=\operatorname{diag}(4,1,1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Solution : $\det(A + A) = \det (2A) = 2^3\det(A)$ since $A$ is $3\times3$, so $\det(A + A) = 2^3 4 = 32.$

Comment: See my edits to this answer for proper MathJax usage. $3x3$ looks quite different from $3\times3,$ and $det(A)$ from $\det(A).$ Notice the difference in spacing to the right of $\det$ between $\det(A)$ and $\det A. \qquad$

Comment: How is this a hint?

Comment: @Servaes Gonna change it to : Solution

Answer (score 0):

You should wrestle this to the ground to get a feel for it.

If $A = (a_{ij})$ then $A + A = (a_{ij}+a_{ij}) = (2a_{ij}) = (b_{ij})$ where $b_{ij} = 2a_{ij}$

Now the determinate of an $n\times n$ matrix will be some sum/difference combination of the product of $n$ $a_ij$ terms.  For example:  for a $3\times 3$  matrix the determinate is $a_{11}a_{22}a_{33} - a_{11}a_{32}a_{23} - a_{1,2}a_{2,1}a_{3,3} + a_{1,2}a_{3,1}a_{2,3} + a_{13}a_{2,1}a_{3,2}-a_{13}a_{22}a_{3,1}$.  We can write that as $\sum\limits_{\text{some conditions}}\pm a_{i,j}a_{k,l}a_{m,n}$.  (We don't actually *care* about the details here.  Those terms are what we *base* the determinate one

so the determinate of $(b_{ij}) = ([2a_{ij}])$ will be

$\sum\limits_{\text{some conditions}}\pm b_{i,j}b_{k,l}b_{m,n}=$

$\sum\limits_{\text{some conditions}}\pm 2\cdot a_{i,j}2\cdot a_{k,l}2\cdot a_{m,n}$

$\sum\limits_{\text{some conditions}}\pm 2^3a_{i,j}a_{k,l}a_{m,n}=$

$2^3\sum\limits_{\text{some conditions}}\pm a_{i,j}a_{k,l}a_{m,n}=$

$2^3 \det A$

....

And for an $n\times n$ matrix we would have

$\sum\limits_{\text{some conditions}}\pm b_{i,j}b_{k,l}b_{m,p}.......=$

$\sum\limits_{\text{some conditions}}\pm 2\cdot a_{i,j}2\cdot a_{k,l}2\cdot a_{m,p}.......$

$\sum\limits_{\text{some conditions}}\pm 2^na_{i,j}a_{k,l}a_{m,p}......=$

$2^n\sum\limits_{\text{some conditions}}\pm a_{i,j}a_{k,l}a_{m,p}......=$

$2^n \det A$.